# How do I have excel delete everything except the last 6 digits in all entries of a column?

Tags: excel

I have hundreds of serial numbers that need to be shortened to only the last 6 digits (which we use for our stock numbers). Can any of you wizards out there help make this monthly task a ton easier for me?

I'm in Excel 2007.

Comment: In a helper column (say column B), '=IF(LEN(A1)>=6,RIGHT(A1,6),A1)`, copy down, then paste special value over the orginal column

Answer (score 3):

You can simply retrieve the last 6 digits (characters) with `RIGHT`:

```
        A       B
1   1234567 =RIGHT(A1,6)
2   7654321 =RIGHT(A2,6)
```

Will give you the last 6 characters from cell A1. The result is a text string.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! Unfortunately excel keeps telling me that I'm creating a circular reference and I end up with just 6 zeros in the field.

Comment: @user3516882 You need to put this formula in a different cell. If the serial number is in cell A1, you need to put it in a cell different than A1. This is how formulae work in excel. Once you get the new list of numbers, you need to remove the formulae by copy/pasting as values (Copy > Paste Special > Paste Values) and then you can remove the previous ones.

Comment: Above 1 and 2 are standing for the row and A and B for the column.